# Amazon Web Service/Boto: Upload and execute remote python/bash script via SSH on localhost

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, boto

I am able to fire up [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) Ubuntu EC2 instance with [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/). Have anyone tried to upload the script to the remote Ubuntu EC2 (More than 1) and execute the script via SSH locally?

The main objective is to automate the whole process using a Python script written on localhost. Is there an alternative way or Amazon api tools to made this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/) API

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.1/index.html), it's made for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here, Paramiko code to execute in remote AWS EC2 Python :

```
import paramiko
sftp, transport= None, None,  None
try:
    if keyfilepath=='': keyfilepath= AWS_KEY_PEM
    if keyfiletype == 'DSA':  key = paramiko.DSSKey.from_private_key_file(keyfilepath)
    else:                     key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(keyfilepath)

    if contype== 'sftp' :
      transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
      transport.add_server_key(key)
      transport.connect(None, username,  pkey=key)
      sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
      if isprint : print('Root Directory :\n ', sftp.listdir())
      return sftp

except Exception as e:
    print('An error occurred creating client: %s: %s' % (e.__class__, e))
    if sftp is not None:      sftp.close()
    if transport is not None: transport.close()
    if ssh is not None: ssh.close()
```